# Show the following statements are equivalent - convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set.

Show the following are equivalent:

(a) The set $C$ is convex.

(b) The function $\delta_C : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \infty$ defined as:
$$\delta_C(x):= 0 \space \space \text{if} \space \space x  \in C$$
$$\delta_C(x):= +\infty \space \space  \text{if} \space \space x \notin C$$
is a convex function

Attempt:

If $C$ is convex $\exists \space u,v \in C, \lambda \in [0,1]$ such that

$\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v \in C$

And $\exists x,y \notin C, \lambda \in [0,1]$ such that

$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \notin C$
$\therefore (a) \implies (b)$

Is this sufficient for the first half of the entire proof?
Particularly I was trying to show that the for some $u,v$ implies the top part of the $\delta_C(x)$ whereas the other part implies the bottom equivalence since $+\infty \notin C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different, more geometric approach:

A function $f$ is convex **iff** $\operatorname{epi} f$ is convex.

Note that $\operatorname{epi} \delta_C = C \times [0,\infty)$, and
$C \times [0,\infty)$ is convex **iff** $C$ is convex.

Comment: Could you please explain how the last iff holds? I understand if $A, B$ are both convex then $A \times B$ is also convex. But how do we get if $A \times B$ is convex then both $A, B$ are convex? It seems you are using this statement with $A := C$, and $B := [0, \infty)$ above. If so, could you please proved the proof details on this?

Comment: @user4687531 I am assuming that both $A,B$ are non empty. Suppose $A \times B$ is convex. Pick some $b \in B$ and $a_1,a_2 \in A$. Then with $t \in [0,1]$ you have $t(a_1,b)+(1-t)(a_2,b) \in A \times B$ and hence $ta_1 +(1-t)a_2 \in A$. Similarly for $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @copper.hat. Just to ensure I understand fully. The statement you have used (and the one direction of which you just proved) is: Let $A, B$ be non-empty sets. Then $A \times B$ is convex if and only if $A, B$ are both convex. Is that correct?

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, I used that for the very last clause above.

Comment: Many thanks for the confirmation and for the very nice proof!

Comment: @user4687531 You are welcome :-).